# What is best practice for flagging or removing a tag on a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just reviewing [a question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/autocreating-new-node-based-on-non-existing-node-reference) with three tags. The latter two tag appear to be new and vague.  I have been cautiously editing tags, usually to add a tag where needed. I am not sure about deleting one.  Is it appropriate to do so?  (I don't even know if I have the permission to do so; I'll ask this on meta as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to remove a tag that is not much helpful, or that should not be used. While you are editing the question, check there isn't anything else that needs to be corrected: spelling, grammar, and everything else that can make the question clearer without changing its meaning.

You cannot edit every post, until your reputation is not at least 2,000. Your edits will be queued, and approved.